# Kendo UI Dropdownlist with template set selected value doesn't work

Tags: kendo-ui

I am trying to use a Kendo Dropdownlist that uses a template.  I have a page where a user can select a dataset and that dataset with populate dropdowns with values.  Most of my dropdowns do not use templates however the one that isn't working properly is using templates.

My template:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="dropdownTemplate">
  <div>
    <p><strong>#= Name #</strong></p>
    <p>#= Description #</p>
  </div>
</script>
```

My dropdown definition:

```
$("#listTemplates").kendoDropDownList({
 dataTextField: "Name",
 dataValueField: "ChartTemplateId",
 template: kendo.template($("#dropdownTemplate").html()),
 change: listTemplatesChange
});
```

How I am populating my dropdown:

```
 portalTemplatesModel = [
 [{
   Name: "Test",
   Description: "Long Description",
   ChartTemplateId: "1"
 }],
 [{
   Name: "Test2",
   Description: "Long Description2",
   ChartTemplateId: "2"
 }]
 ]
 for (i = 0; i < portalTemplatesModel.length; i++) {

   $("#listTemplates").data("kendoDropDownList").dataSource.add(portalTemplatesModel[i]);
 }
```

My setter:

```
var ddTemplates = $("#listTemplates").data("kendoDropDownList");
 ddTemplates.select(function (dataItem) {
 return dataItem.value === placeHolderChart.ChartTemplateId;
});
```

dataItem looks like the following:

```
 [{
   Name: "Test",
   Description: "Long Description",
   ChartTemplateId: "1"
 }]
```

I noticed in the setter documentation you are supposed to use either value or item.  However, with the dataset that I am using it seems to use a different object that does not contain value or text like the other dropdowns that don't use templates have.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem. What seemed to work was adding data. in front of your calls to the datasource values. 
i.e. #=data.Description #

Comment: I used the same template for a ComboBox and there I didn't to put "data." in front. This is strange.

Answer (score 0):

you can populate it by having ${Name} and ${Description} in your kendoTemplate, when the data source is read, the template will get the values and you can see it according to you template.